# pass class instance parameters for easy instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

About twelve of my unittests use a class with six parameters where one or two of them is systematically modified for the test. It feels like there is a fair bit of repetition. I want to get rid of the repetition and make it very clean and explicit what is modified within the six parameters for each test. The code is a bit error prone otherwise, if you accidentally have an attribute out of place for something with `assertFalse`, the test may succeed but not for the reason you are testing for.

I was going to just instantiate the class up the top of the script, make a `deepcopy` of it for each test and modify its attributes as needed, due to some need for flask context, that looks like it is getting messy.

```
base_instance = SomeClass(
                  firstparameter = "dog",
                  secondparameter = 5,
                  thirdparameter = [7, 8],
                  fourthparameter = 5.5,
                  fifthparameter = "bar"
                  sixthparameter = "foo"
)
```

The thing is, the set of keyword parameters inside the brackets is not really a python object you can easily put in a variable, pass around or lightly modify. Is it possible to give the class its parameters in a dictionary or some other structure somehow, so I can easily make instances with systematic changes in a `deepcopy` of the object which holds the parameters? I want it to stay explicit with keywords, so not start messing around with lists and positional arguments.

Comment: You can absolutely use a dictionary as keyword parameters, that's what `**` is for: `SomeClass(**{"firstparameter": "dog", ...})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this.

```
params = {
    'firstparameter': "dog",
    'secondparameter': 5,
    'thirdparameter': [7, 8],
    'fourthparameter': 5.5,
    'fifthparameter': "bar",
    'sixthparameter': "foo"
}
base_instance = SomeClass(**params)
```